Merge two traces in grafana tempo
I’m currently working on a project using OpenTelemetry to instrument FastAPI services, and we’re using Grafana Tempo as the tracing backend. I have a scenario where I need to combine two separate traces under the same trace_id or represent them as a single trace in Grafana.
I’ve gone through several resources, including:

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/transforming-telemetry/
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor
https://speakerdeck.com/jpkroehling/building-custom-opentelemetry-collector-distributions-with-ocb?slide=12

Can I use the OpenTelemetry Collector to transform and manipulate traces before sending them to Tempo? I’m still unsure about the best way to merge two separate traces under the same trace_id using a transformation pipeline
Specifically, I would appreciate insights on:
• Whether it is feasible to configure a transformation pipeline in Grafana Tempo or the OpenTelemetry Collector to handle merging traces at the collector level.
• Any existing mechanisms or best practices for joining traces or managing context propagation across multiple requests that might help solve this problem.

Why do you need to join multiple traces? Sounds like you rather want to propagate trace Id. What's the use case where trace id is not propagated?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
